# How do I handle Hashtable nulls in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

I'm porting some java code across and have the following

```
val overnightChanges: java.util.Hashtable[String, Double] = ...
```

When I try

```
if (null != overnightChanges.get(...))
```

I get the following warning

warning: comparing values of types Null and Double using `!=' will always yield true

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Primitive and reference types are much less different in scala than they are in java, and so the convention is that name starts with an uppercase for all of them. `Double` is `scala.Double` which is the primitive java `double`, not the reference `java.lang.Double`.

When you need "a double or no value" in scala, you would use `Option[Double]` most of the time. Option has  strong library support, and the type system will not let you ignore that there might be no value. However, when you need to interact closely with java, as in your example, your table does contain java.lang.Double and you should say it so.

```
val a = new java.util.HashMap[String, java.lang.Double]
```

If `java.lang.Double` starts to appear everywhere in your code, you can alias to JDouble, either by importing

```
import java.lang.{Double => JDouble}
```

or by defining

```
type JDouble = java.lang.Double
```

There are implicit conversions between `scala.Double` and `java.lang.Double`, so interaction should be reasonably smooth. However, `java.lang.Double` should probably be confined to the scala/java interaction layer, it would be confusing to have it go deep into scala code.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `Option(javaHashtable.get(...))` will turn the "java.lang.Double or null" into an `Option[java.lang.Double]`. In general, it's good practice to wrap nullable Java methods with `Option` to prevent `null` from leaking into Scala code.

Comment: Also, when you say "double or no value", I think you mean "double or nothing" (but *not* "Double or Nothing"). ;-)

Comment: (For non-native English speakers, please excuse the pun)

Comment: There used to be a radio game in France with a similar name. Not sure how it was capitalized though.

Comment: In U.S. English, at least, "double or nothing" is an idiom for an opportunity to either double one's winnings or lose them all (in a game) -- unfortunately, nullable methods only offer the latter.  With "Double or Nothing", I was referring to the Scala types.

Answer (score 5):

In Scala Double are primitives and thus cannot be null. That's annoying when using directly java maps, because when a key is not defined, you get the default primitive value, (here 0.0):

```
scala>  val a = new java.util.Hashtable[String,Double]()
a: java.util.Hashtable[String,Double] = {}

scala> a.get("Foo")
res9: Double = 0.0
```

If the value is a object like String or List, your code should work as expected.

So, to solve the problem, you can:

1. Use `contains` in an outer if condition.
2. Use one of the Scala maps (many conversions are defined in `scala.collection.JavaConversions`)

Answer (score 0):

Use Scala "options", also known as "maybe" in Haskell:

http://blog.danielwellman.com/2008/03/using-scalas-op.html

Comment: That  blog doesn't address the OP's issue with java.util.Hashtable. It uses a Scala collection instead